# How to send msg to device and wait for the response by aws IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I used Aws IoT Device management to register my laptop as a device and run a node js script on my laptop.
My laptop will publish the message to a topic and it also can subscribe to a topic.
But what I want is, aws cloud send msg to my deivce( which is my laptop), periodically, if my laptop doesn't give the responses back to the cloud, cloud will know that my device is dead.
But how to send msg to my device and wait for the response? I read the tutorial about the jobs and shadow in aws IoT device management, none of them are sending something to device, they are just existing on the cloud and device will go and grab them.
How to make aws IoT device management automatically send msg or publish the msg to the device? All I know is go to the "Test" page and publish to the topic the manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you're trying to use AWS IoT to create a monitoring system to detect if your device (laptop) is alive or not.

Sending data from the cloud -> laptop is not needed. You can do this by only sending data from your laptop -> cloud.

Configure the Node.JS script on your laptop to periodically send messages to a topic in AWS IoT. Configure an [AWS IoT Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rules.html) on that topic that will publish a metric to AWS CloudWatch. This metric will represent your laptop sending a heartbeat to the cloud.

You can additionally configure an [alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) in AWS CloudWatch to watch this metric and perform an action if the alarm threshold is ever breached. For your use case you can probably set the alarm to breach when it's missing data points because that'll mean your laptop has stopped sending messages.